# How to solve this nonlinear equation in Python, Octave, or Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, math, octave, equation-solving

How do I solve this equation using Python, Octave, or Matlab?

[image: equation]

Need to be able to find the solution of *x* for different values of *c*.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please be sure to check out [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for ideas on how to make this more complete and better formatted.  As is, I'm not sure what you're asking, and the content being behind an image makes it very hard to search for.

Comment: Is `c` restricted to the condition `c ≥ 0`? It seems that at if `c > 0` solutions exist, and for `c = 0`, then `x = 0` by inspection.  However, negative values of `c` appear problematic.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Solvers](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html)

```
# this is an example
>>> from sympy.solvers import solve
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> solve(x ** 2 - 1, x)
[-1, 1]
```

Comment: I tried solving for c=1 but the editor has thrown this error.
"No algorithms are implemented to solve equation x + log(1 - 267/(1000*x))"

Comment: try this : from sympy.solvers import nsolve /// from sympy import Symbol, log /// x = Symbol('x') /// nsolve(x + log(1 - 267/(1000*x)), x,1)

Answer (score 3):

As the equation has some float constants, it is probably best to use `nsolve` to solve it numerically:

```py
from sympy import Eq, log, exp, nsolve
from sympy.abc import x

c = 267
sol = nsolve(Eq(x ** 0.22 * (c * exp(-c * x ** 0.22) - 1), c * log(0.7657)), x, 1)
print(sol)  # 264587674.024352
```

Answer (score 3):

**No Toolbox Required:**

In MATLAB, you can use [`fminsearch()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) to do this numerically.

The key idea is to rewrite the equation `y = w` as `y - w = 0`. Then, construct a [convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) to guarantee you the local minima returned is indeed globally optimal, e.g. `abs(y-w)`.

```
% Rewrite equation y = w as y - w = 0.
% Then minimize abs(y-w).
fh =@(x,c) abs((x.^(0.22)).*(c*exp(-c*(x.^(0.22)))-1) - c*log(0.7657));

c = 267;
x0 = 5;                                      % initial guess
[x, abserr] = fminsearch(@(x) fh(x,c),x0)    % x = 264587674.0243530
```

Note that `abserr = 4.2633e-14` which is pretty darn close to zero (equality).

Similarly, you could minimize the sum of squared error to achieve the same answer.

```
% minimize sum((y-w).^2)
gh =@(x,c) sum(((x.^(0.22)).*(c*exp(-c*(x.^(0.22)))-1) - c*log(0.7657)).^2);
[x, sse] = fminsearch(@(x) fh(x,c),x0)
```

---

Rather than using [`arrayfun()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html), to get the different `x` values for each `c` value, it is probably easier just to loop through.

```
C = [100 267 300].';
Xval = zeros(size(C));
for ii = 1:length(C)
    Xval(ii) = fminsearch(@(x) fh(x,C(ii)),x0);
end
```

---

**Not Recommended:**
While [`fzero()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) will also work to solve `y - w = 0`, notice that it aborts searching for an interval containing a sign change (if `x` is negative). So you either have to add a penalty for that direction somehow, or try from a different starting value.

```
% solve y-w==0
zh =@(x,c) (x.^(0.22)).*(c*exp(-c*(x.^(0.22)))-1) - c*log(0.7657)
```

Using the same starting point,

```
x = fzero(@(x) zh(x,c),x0)
```

returns the error

> Exiting fzero: aborting search for an interval containing a sign
>   change
>       because complex function value encountered during search. (Function value at -1.4 is 70.4499-0.686399i.) Check function or try
>   again with a different starting value. x = NaN

while

```
x = fzero(@(x) zh(x,c),2e8)       % adjusted starting guess
```

works just fine.

<sub>Tested with MATLAB R2019a</sub>